# How do I search for a substring in a char* from a starting index using C?

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following loop which calls the `parseXML()` function:

```
...

char buffer[MAX_BUFSIZE];
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
int bytes_received = tcp_read(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

...

int bytes_read_total = 0;
while (bytes_read_total < bytes_received) {
        
    int bytes_read = 0;
    Person* person = parseXML(buffer, bytes_received - bytes_read_total, &bytes_read);

    if (person == NULL) break;

    bytes_read_total += bytes_read;
    savePerson(person);

}
```

and I here is the start of my `parseXML()` function:

```
Person* parseXML(char* buffer, int bufSize, int* bytesRead) {
    
    char* startTag = strstr(buffer, "<person>");
    char* endTag = strstr(buffer, "</person>");
    if (startTag == NULL || endTag == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Person* person = newPerson();
    
    int personLength = endTag + strlen("</person>") - startTag;

    char* personBuffer = (char*)malloc(personLength + 1);
    memcpy(personBuffer, startTag, personLength);
    personBuffer[personLength] = '\0';

    ...

    free(personBuffer);
    *bytesRead = personLength + 1;
    return person;
```

When using `strstr()` currently it is always finding the first person in my xml each iteration instead of starting the search from the bytesRead offset. Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: `strstr(buffer+bytesRead, "<person>")`

Comment: Writing ad hoc code to parse XML is asking for trouble.  Use an XML parsing library instead.

Comment: Unless `ParseXML` is supposed to change `buffer`, it should be `const char *buffer` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strstr` accepts a char pointer as its first parameter, and stops searching when it reaches a null character (end-of-string).

Pointers can be used in arithmetic, for example:

```c
    int nums[2] = {1, 2};
    int *secondnum = nums + 1;  // "nums" array decays (turns) into a pointer
    printf("%d\n", *secondnum);  // prints "2"
```

As such, to search a string starting from an offset using `strstr`, all you need to do is increment your pointer:

```c
    char *haystack = "foo 1, foo 2";
    char *needle = "foo";

    char *first_foo = strstr(haystack, needle);
    char *second_foo = strstr(first_foo + strlen(needle), needle);
    printf("%td\n", second_foo - haystack);  // prints "7", the position of the second "foo"
```

When `strstr` doesn't find the substring, it returns a NULL pointer. You can check if the substring was found doing the following:

```c
    char *found = strstr(haystack, needle);
    if (found != NULL) {
        // found is a pointer to the position of the substring
    } else {
        // substring not found
    }
```

Comment: UB - use he correct format specyfiers

Comment: What if needle is "boo" or haystack "a"?

Comment: This isn't UB, `%ld` is the correct format specifier on x86_64 (ptrdiff_t is long int), and the value is always small enough to fit without data loss anyway. I'd have to use C23 extensions to make this fully correct across architectures.

Comment: As for your second comment, strstr() returns the end of the string if nothing can be matched. While haystack + 3 will be UB if the string isn't long enough, this example was meant to be illustrative with the given parameters. You should always make sure to check against buffer overruns.

Comment: *"`strstr()` returns the end of the string if nothing can be matched"* - are you sure? I would suggest to read the documentation

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is `long int` - no,  `ptrdiff_t` **is** `ptrdiff_t`, nothing else

Comment: I did read the documentation, but I misinterpreted what it said. Thanks for correcting me, though it'd be nice if you dropped the condescending tone.
On the `ptrdiff_t` note, you left out a crucial part of the quote, and I genuinely don't know how to action on this without relying on this equivalence that exists on every common 64-bit and 32-bit architecture.

Comment: Massive misunderstanding. And you started the argument instead of rereading it. Generally, you should only answer the question if you know the correct answer. And the answer should point to all possible problems.

Comment: *"On the ptrdiff_t note, you left out a crucial part of the quote, and I genuinely don't know how to action on this without relying on this equivalence"* - again do the research before you answer or comment. I will help you: the correct one is `"%td"`

Comment: Thanks. I did do my research, and I answered in good faith as to what I thought was a correct answer, but nothing is right on the first try. Playing the blame-game isn't particularly helpful.